# Tinymce show html tags

Tags: php, jquery, html, tinymce-4

I have a problem with Tinymce Editor.

I'm trying to use it in a comments system with jQuery but it display HTML tags .

```
<p>test</p>
```

And when I look to the inserted text in DB I found this

```
&lt;p&gt;test&lt;/p&gt;
```

I don't know what's the problem, and this is the JavaScript code that I use:

```
e.preventDefault();
if(working) return false;
working = true;
$('#submit').val('Working..');
$('span.error').remove();
$.post('submit.php',$(this).serialize(),function(msg){ 
.....
```

and I use a simple php without any security.

Comment: What are you using to display the output? If it has a "HTMLEncode" property, set it to False

Comment: error !== js!!!! hope this is what help you better to look up.

Comment: thats wwysiwyg for! it will convert them to HTML code when save! if you dont want the html code in it, just use plain textarea!

Comment: @tonoslfx i didn't understand what you mean

Comment: @KieranQuinn i don't know what's the problem , i did use nice.Edit before and it work fine but when i want to use Tinymce i get that problem

Comment: @Jai what do you mean ?

Comment: Where are you seeing the `<p>test</p>`? What type of field is it? Or even what type of application is displaying it? Internet browser? Mobile app?

Comment: @KieranQuinn . it's a comment system like this ( you type a comment and when you submit the form it appear above the text area so there whare i see '<p>test</p>' ) the field is textarea and  it's internet browser